# Unable to decode an image and form a matrix

Tags: python, image, image-processing, decode

I want to decode the image and make a matrix of it for further processing. I only obtain an empty list after the following code implementation

```
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode
from PIL import Image

decode(Image.open("here.png"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using OpenCV for this purpose...? It is a much powerful image processing library

```
import cv2 #importing opencv
img = cv2.imread('filename.jpg', 0) 
      #1st param: image file. 2nd param: 1 - color, 0 - grayscale
#img contains a matrix of the image file
```